# TabControl: SelectedContent and SelectedItem return the same

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I'm displaying a list of custom objects (here: Customer) dynamicly, each in its own tab using TabControl, ItemsSource and DataTemplate:

MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace testTabControl
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfContracts { get; set; }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //create all
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer {FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith", NumberOfContracts = 23},
                new Customer {FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smiths", NumberOfContracts = 42},
                new Customer {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Tester", NumberOfContracts = 32}
            };

            //show
            myTabControl.ItemsSource = customers;

        }

        private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("myTabControl.SelectedContent is " + myTabControl.SelectedContent.GetType());
            Trace.WriteLine("myTabControl.SelectedItem    is " + myTabControl.SelectedItem.GetType());

            // do something with content of the selected tab:
            ///myTabControl.SelectedContent.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        }
    }    
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="testTabControl.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:testTabControl="clr-namespace:testTabControl" 
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
            SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged"
            >
        <Window.Resources>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="myContent" DataType="{x:Type testTabControl:Customer}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="myContentRoot">
                    This is the content for 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/> <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="myHeader" DataType="{x:Type testTabControl:Customer}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Window.Resources>

        <TabControl 
            x:Name="myTabControl" 
            SelectedIndex="0" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myHeader}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myContent}"
         />

    </Window>
```

In the method OnSizeChanged I expected myTabControl.SelectedContent to return a TextBlock generated from DataTemplate. But an instance of Customer is returned! Same as by myTabControl.SelectedItem.

The only way I found to get the generated content is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

Does anybody know any other solution without visual tree walk?

Answer (score 2):

Your `TabControl` contains objects of type `Customer`. `Templates` can be used to tell WPF how to draw each `Customer` object, however it doesn't change the fact that the items in the `TabControl` are still `Customer` objects.

If you want to access a templated UI object for the item, you can either walk the `VisualTree` or use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to get the container holding the `SelectedItem`

For example,

```
var selectedItem = myTabControl.SelectedItem;

var selectedItemContainer = 
    myTabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem);
```

Comment: selectedItemContainer is then an instance of TabItem, whose Content attribute is still an instance of Customer, not the elements generated from template. So I still cannot access the textBlock named myContentRoot.

Comment: @vofka Once you have the container object, you can use `selectedItemContainer.FindName("TextBoxName")` to find the TextBox object, or you can traverse the `VisualTree` to find other elements. I have a set of [Visual Tree Helpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) you might be interested in using if `FindName` doesn't work for you.

Comment: selectedItemContainer.FindName("TextBoxName") doesn't find the TextBox. Only traversing VisualTree works. I thought there were a solution like placing content provider or binding some properties of the TabControl expicitely or something like that, to get access to the generated elements and avoid the VisualTree traversing.

Comment: @vofka If your item in the TabControl is a UI element instead of a data object that would probably work, however it doesn't work when it's a data object since you are using a Template. Templated items don't exist in the VisualTree until they get drawn, and then they're just a copy of the template. What you're asking is kind of like trying to find out what type of cookie is being made just by looking at the cookie cutter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your SelectedContent is returning a Customer object is this:

`<DataTemplate x:Key="myContent" DataType="{x:Type testTabControl:Customer}">`

It is returning exactly what you ask for.  All the DataTemplate does is describe how to display the Customer object which *is* the content, nothing else.  When you ask for content, it returns the object that the DataTemplate is displaying.

One way that you could do this house a property on your Customer object which replicates the output you want.

```
public string OutputString
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("This is the content for {0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
    }

}
```

And then do something like

```
Trace.WriteLine("myTabControl.SelectedContent is " + myTabControl.SelectedContent.OutputString);
```

Or you might could create a collection of strings that followed the format above, and make those the content.  Then your SelectedContent would be a simple string by default.

Comment: I don't want to change the Customer class, because I don't want manipulate the Customer instance, but the way it is presented. So I would like to get access to the elementes created from the DataTemplate (if they are really generated and not the template itself is referenced) and change some presentation properties on them.